# Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views. When running animation

Tags: android, kotlin, animation, kotlin-coroutines

I can't figure out what is wrong in here, looks like Timer is causing this issue but even if I remove Timer line completely it still crashing with error like thi "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views."

Maybe you guys can suggest a different way to run animations inside of an activity to avoid this.

Another interesting thing is that it runs perfectly fine on Android 12, but crashing on Android 7.

Here is the code that sitting inside of Activity:

```
private fun setAnimations() {
        fadeInErrorMessage.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {
                binding.mainErrorMessageContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
                Timer("ErrorMessage", false).schedule(1500L) {
                    binding.mainErrorMessageContainer.startAnimation(fadeOutErrorMessage)
                }
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
        })

        fadeOutErrorMessage.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {
            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation) {}

            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
                binding.mainErrorMessageContainer.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                errorMessageAnimationIsRunning = false
            }

            override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation) {}
        })
    }
```

Here is logs:

```
2022-09-14 21:24:22.981 17059-17371/com.company.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ErrorMessage
    Process: com.company.app, PID: 17059
    android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6892)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:1083)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:5205)
        at android.view.View.invalidateInternal(View.java:13657)
        at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:13621)
        at android.view.View.startAnimation(View.java:20175)
        at com.company.app.ui.main.MainActivity$setAnimations$1$onAnimationEnd$$inlined$schedule$1.run(Timer.kt:149)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run your animations inside `runOnUiThread()`:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
     void run() {
        binding.mainErrorMessageContainer.visibility = View.VISIBLE
     }
});

runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         void run() {    
            binding.mainErrorMessageContainer.startAnimation(fadeOutErrorMessage)
         }
    });
```

**Edit**: it looks like your specific error refers to the onAnimationEnd, where you're running Timer.schedule(). So you should try to make that method look like this:

```
override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
    Timer("ErrorMessage", false).schedule(1500L) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            void run(){
               binding.mainErrorMessageContainer.startAnimation(fadeOutErrorMessage)
            }
        });
                    
    }
}
```

Comment: I just put it this way and it still throws the same error, literally wrapped anything that was inside animation in `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {})`

Comment: what's the actual line where you get that error?

Comment: Also, to be clear, I don't know what you mean when you say that you "literally wrapped anything that was inside animation`. You should have only wrapped specific lines that actually require a UI thread, just like I posted in my answer

Comment: Well yeah that's what I meant, lines that interacting with UI, not the whole method.
And it does not give me a specific line, eveything that I am getting about this errors in logs I posted below the code

Comment: The error line looks to be in `onAnimationEnd`, where you're running `Timer.schedule()`. I just want to make sure that your set up runOnUiThread `runOnUiThread()` inside Timer.schedule

Comment: I forgot that I had multiple Activities with Timer that was causing this issue, I wrapped lines inside Timer in Runnable and it fixed the issue, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation) {
        Timer("ErrorMessage", false).schedule(1500L) {
            binding.mainErrorMessageContainer.startAnimation(fadeOutErrorMessage)
        }
    }
```

You can't do it on a timer like that.  That causes it to happen on a different thread.  Assuming you created the UI on the main thread, put the body of the timer (the binding.mainError part) inside a runOnUiThread block.  If you created the UI on a different thread, you should probably fix that first.

You can tell that its the endAnimation call that's causing the problem because it's the one calling startAnimation, and its the one that's in the stack trace.